# Monthly wise count using date calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the table named company  with columns *company name*, *create date*, etc.

I want to get the count of companies created for this month.

I have the stored procedure for weekly wise count

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_NewCmpCount]  
                            @StartDate DATETIME = NULL --'20130508'
                        , @EndDate DATETIME = NULL --'20130515'

    AS 
    BEGIN
    DECLARE   @DateDiff INT
        , @MainDate DATETIME


    IF @StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL
    BEGIN
    IF (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) > 3)

    SET @DateDiff = 0
    ELSE
    SET @DateDiff = 6

    SET @MainDate = DATEADD (MINUTE, -30, DATEADD (HOUR, -5, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,@DateDiff,GETDATE()), 0)))


    SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD (MINUTE, -30, DATEADD (HOUR, -5, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@MainDate), -5)))

    SELECT @EndDate = DATEADD (MINUTE, -30, DATEADD (HOUR, -5, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@MainDate), 2)))

    SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR,  Count(*)) AS [Count]
    , CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)) AS [StartDate]
    , CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate) AS [EndDate]
    FROM 
    Company WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE CreateDate >= @StartDate 
    AND CreateDate  < @EndDate

    END
    ELSE 
    IF ((CONVERT (DATE, @StartDate) < CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate)) AND (CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate) < CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())))

    BEGIN       

    SET @StartDate = CONVERT (DATE, @StartDate)

    SET @EndDate = CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate)

    SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD (MINUTE, -30, DATEADD (HOUR, -5, @StartDate))

    SELECT @EndDate = DATEADD (MINUTE, 30, DATEADD (HOUR, 18, @EndDate))

    SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR,  Count(*)) AS [Count]
    , CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)) AS [StartDate]
    , CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate) AS [EndDate]
    FROM 
    Company WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE CreateDate >= @StartDate 
    AND CreateDate  < @EndDate
    END
    ELSE
    SELECT 'Please Run After Tuesday of Every Week or Given the Valid Date' [Count]
    , CONVERT (DATE, @StartDate) AS [StartDate]
    , CONVERT (DATE, @EndDate) AS [EndDate]

    END
```

Output for this stored procedure is

```
         Count  Startdate      EndDate
             10    2016-03-13     2016-03-22
```

Expected output

```
         Count  Startdate      EndDate
             20    2016-02-01     2016-02-29
```

Where do I need to modify in my stored procedure to get monthly wise count?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDt Date
DECLARE @EndDt date
SELECT @StartDt,@EndDt,Count(*) AS TotalCompanies FROM company
WHERE [create date] BETWEEN @StartDt AND @EndDt
```

I skipped the stored procedure formatting for simplicity.